# Use custom environment variable in NuGet pack action of Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create an Azure build pipeline where the build number is generated by Powershell. So I have these two tasks:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $env:NugetVersion = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME;
   
   if ($env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME.StartsWith("dev-") -eq $true) {
       $env:NugetVersion = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME.SubString(4) + "." + (Get-Date).Ticks / 1000
   }
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    configuration: Release
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: NugetVersion
```

I simply define the environment variable "NugetVersion" in the powershell script and then I try to use it in the "NuGet pack" command. I don't use $ or $env or whatever, as mentioned in the tooltip in Azure UI, but the result is always the same:

> ##[error]No value was found for the provided environment variable.

Do I have to create this variable somewhere upfront before executing the pipeline?
Note that I tried to `Write-Host` the value of the variable as the last line of the script and it outputs the correct value, so I don't really understand how come the NuGet task tells me it does not find the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I don't really understand how come the NuGet task tells me it does not find the variable.

That because the task in the pipeline could not directly identify environment variables.

We need use the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to set this variable in the last line of the Inline powershell task:

```
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=NugetVersion]$env:NugetVersion")
```

In this case, the next task could use the this variable.

Now, I could use command line task to show it:

```
echo $(NugetVersion)
```

[image]

**However**, another problem is that you could not set the variable as the package version, because it does not meet the specified rules of the package version, and the package version needs to comply with [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](https://semver.org/). If we use that variable, we will get following error:

```
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Version string specified for package reference 'er.637402549809904' is invalid.
```

[image]

So, if the powershell script you provide is your real script, you may also need to reconsider how to get a valid package version.

**BTW**, for the `$env:NugetVersion = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME;`, it seems you are set the branch **name** rather than a number as nuget version, This seems unreasonable, you may need to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks, it works. For your last comment, it is because I want some branch name like "dev-1.3.2", when I build this knew it should create a package like "1.3.2-rc.xyz". Then I want to create a release pipeline based on this branch that will create a new branch with the same name but without "dev-" and the build it. Il just experimenting.